# Common roots to "independent" equations $P_1(x) = Q_1(y)$ and $P_2(x) = Q_2(y)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

**Problem:**

> let $P_1(x), P_2(x), Q_1(y), Q_2(y)$ be some polynomials of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let
> \begin{equation}
> A := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2 : P_1(x) = Q_1(y) \},\\
> B := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2 : P_2(x) = Q_2(y) \}.
> \end{equation}
> Let us also assume that equations $P_1(x) = Q_1(y)$ and $P_2(x) = Q_2(y)$ are independent in certain sense: for example, polynomials $P_1(x) - Q_1(y)$ and $P_2(x) - Q_2(y)$ do not have common divisors.
> Can one imply that
> $$|A \cap B| \ll \max{(|A|, |B|)}  ?$$

This is clear that each of the equations $P(x) = Q(y)$ may have at most $dp$ solutions, and this is nearly attained when, for example, $P(x) = x^d + 3, Q(y) = y^d + 3$, where $d | p - 1$.

There is the following variation of Bombieri's result by Chalk and Smith (see Theorem 2 in [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa18/aa18121.pdf), page 202):

**Theorem.** Let $(b_1, b_2) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$ be nonzero and $f(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{F}_p[x, y]$ be a polynomial of degree $d \geqslant 1$ with the following property: there is no $c \in \mathbb{F}_p$ for which the polynomial $f(x, y)$ is divisible by $b_1x + b_2y + c$. Then
$$
\bigg|
\sum_{(x, y):f(x,y)=0}
e^{2\pi i(b_1x+b_2y)/p}
\bigg| \leqslant 2d^2p^{1/2}.
$$

This is roughly saying, that as long as $P(x) - Q(y)$ does not have any linear divisors, then sets $A, B$ are equidistributed over $\mathbb{F_p} \times \mathbb{F_p}$.

This gives an intuition, that sets $A$ and $B$ should be somehow independent, and probably even an inequality $|A \cap B| \ll |A||B|/p^2 \ll d^2$ could have place, upon a certain condition of independence of polynomials $P_1, P_2, Q_1, Q_2$.

Are there any known results of this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound $d^2$ is, indeed, correct. It follows from Bézout's theorem, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#Plane_curves). In your case, affine plane curves are exactly $A$ and $B$, the condition on common divisor is the lack of common component. You can take $F=\mathbb F_p$ and $E=\overline{\mathbb F_p}$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!